# Passing args in scipy optimize.minimize objective function ( getting error on number of arguments)

Tags: python, scipy, optimization

I'm trying to use scipy's optimizer.minimize function but I'm unable to figure out exact way to pass args to objective function. I have following code which according to me should work fine but is giving me error on number of arguments.

```
result = minimize(compute_cost, x0, args=(parameter), method='COBYLA',constraints=cons, options={'maxiter':10000,'rhobeg':20})
```

Here is the function signature to objective function: `def compute_cost(x,parameter)`

`parameter` is a dict that has 51 key value pair.

This gives following error:

`capi_return is NULL
Call-back cb_calcfc_in__cobyla__user__routines failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..\resource_optimizer.py", line 138, in <module>
    result = minimize(compute_cost, x0, args=(parameter), method='COBYLA',constraints=cons, options={'maxiter':10000,'rhobeg':20})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 432, in minimize
    return _minimize_cobyla(fun, x0, args, constraints, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py", line 246, in _minimize_cobyla
    dinfo=info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\cobyla.py", line 238, in calcfc
    f = fun(x, *args)
TypeError: compute_cost() takes exactly 2 arguments (52 given)`

Can someone help me figure this out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `args=(parameter)` to `args=(parameter,)`, so `args` is a tuple containing a single element.

`args=(parameter)` is equivalent to `args=parameter`.  When you do that, each element of `parameter` is passed as a separate argument to your objective function.